# Mobile App Email Invitation - Some users have downloaded app already and others haven't

Tags: ios

We have an enterprise iOS application and use an email invitation to invite employees to participate in a 2 day event using the app.   Some employees have already downloaded the latest app from the app store and others have not -- but we don't know.  What is the best way to handle this in the email invitation?  We'd prefer not to have two different calls to action/two different links for the two scenarios.

Comment: On a personal level I hate the idea of downloading an app for a website unless the app has several major advantages over a site. I'm fairly sure I'm not the only one! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> We'd prefer not to have two different calls to action/two different links for the two scenarios.

So don't.  Just put one link labeled <kbd>Join Event!</kbd> or whatever makes sense.  If your question is "How can my web page determine if the user has my app installed and redirect to different sites/protocols based on that information?" you should check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200) on Stack Overflow.